# How to setup camera properly?

Tags: java, camera, libgdx, coordinates

On my class I'm implementing ApplicationListener, so on my create method this is what I do:

```
public void create(){
camera=new Camera();
camera.setToOrtho(false,screenW,screenH);
}

//then on the render method:
public void render(){
camera.update();
}
```

But then when I use `Gdx.input.getY()` the result is reversed, when I go up the Y coordinate is less and when I go down the it gets higher.For better understanding:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the camera class and the unproject method. That should translate between screen coordinates and world coordinates. (Probably more efficient way to do this, but for illustration):

```
float x = Gdx.input.getX();
float y = Gdx.input.getY();
float z = 0.0f;
Vector3 screenCoordinates = new Vector3(x, y, z);
Vector3 worldCoordinates = camera.unproject(screenCoordinates);
```

Then use the worldCoordinates vector for whatever you need it for.

EDIT: Added small working example and screenshot. My screen capture didn't capture the mouse, thus the red "star". But this simple app displays y coordinates in "initial" and "unprojected" coords as you move the mouse around the screen. Try it for yourself. I think this is what you are getting at, no?

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

public class SimpleInputCoords implements ApplicationListener {
   private OrthographicCamera camera;

   @Override
   public void create() {
      camera = new OrthographicCamera();
      camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
   }

   @Override
   public void render() {
       int x = Gdx.input.getX();
       int y = Gdx.input.getY();
       int z = 0;
       System.out.println("UnmodifiedYCoord:"+y);

       Vector3 screenCoordinates = new Vector3(x, y, z);
       Vector3 worldCoordinates = camera.unproject(screenCoordinates);
       System.out.println("UnprojectedYCoord:"+worldCoordinates.y);
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
   }

   @Override
   public void resize(int width, int height) {
   }

   @Override
   public void pause() {
   }

   @Override
   public void resume() {
   }
```

}

[image]

Comment: I tried it but still the same, when I do this should I remove //camera.setToOrtho() ??

Comment: I edited the answer to add a very small working sample you can try for yourself. Unless I'm misunderstanding the problem you're trying to define.

Comment: How do I implement worldCoordinates ? it's just a Vector3

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In the example I gave worldCoordinates simply holds the worldCoordinates, but with (x,y) "starting" at (0,0), which is what I thought you wanted, instead of at the "y value being reversed with y at the top", like what you were seeing. Maybe I don't understand what you are trying to do at all, and someone else will have to answer your question.

Comment: I wan' t the Y coordinate to be equal to 0 when I touch the bottom of the screen without putting camera.unproject() on a Vector3 .

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say, that's not how it works. The unproject gets what you want. Look at the API for Camera and specifically the unproject method: "Function to translate a point given in screen coordinates to world space. It's the same as GLU gluUnProject, but does not rely on OpenGL. The x- and y-coordinate of vec are assumed to be in screen coordinates (origin is the top left corner, y pointing down, x pointing to the right) as reported by the touch methods in Input." Note the "origin is the top left corner" part. That is what you're seeing. By default, 0,0 is top left. Unproject.

Comment: No worries, I'm still learning too. Some things don't make sense to me initially, either. But there are many layers and levels of abstraction at play here to get you to the point of being able to much easier code a game. libgdx abstracting OpenGL abstracting the different file systems/OSs its targeted for, and so on and so on. Each layer may have its own way of doing its thing efficiently which may look "funny" to the next layer up. Or, at least be confusing to a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

In Java coordinates start in the upper left corner (0,0).  On a 100 x 100, (100,0) would be upper right, and (0, 100) would be lower left.  So the behavior you are seeing is expected.

http://inetjava.sourceforge.net/lectures/part2_applets/InetJava-2.1-2.2-Introduction-to-AWT-and-Applets_files/image001.gif

Comment: So this is just normal when using input module? I noticed that when I render something on the screen the Y coordinate is normal, the lower you go the lower it gets.